# Select XML nodes using TSQL

Tags: xml, t-sql

My SQL Server 2008 database table has a XML field. I would like to select nodes from the field, along with other fields. For example, consider the following table:

```
DECLARE @TestTable AS TABLE ([Id] VARCHAR(20),  [Name] XML )
INSERT INTO @TestTable SELECT 
    '001', 
    '<Name><First>Ross</First><Last>Geller</Last></Name>'
UNION ALL SELECT
    '002', 
    '<Name><First>Rachel</First><Last>Green</Last></Name>'
```

I want the result be:

```
001  |  Ross  |  Geller     
002  | Rachel | Green
```

Is that possible? Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do it:

```
DECLARE @TestTable AS TABLE (
     [Id] VARCHAR(20),
     [Name] XML
    )
INSERT  INTO @TestTable
        SELECT  '001',
                '<Name><First>Ross</First><Last>Geller</Last></Name>'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  '002',
                '<Name><First>Rachel</First><Last>Green</Last></Name>'

SELECT  Id,
        x.value('(/Name/First)[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS [First],
        x.value('(/Name/Last)[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS [Last]
FROM    @TestTable t
CROSS APPLY [Name].nodes('/Name') AS tbl ( x )
```

Comment: You don't need the `CROSS APPLY` line at all if you change `x.value` to `Name.value`

Comment: You're right.  I presented it the way I did because it's more applicable to the general case.