# Select XML nodes alongside table values

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

We have a table which contains XML describing a group of orders which is sent by a remote function. Each row also contains things like an ID, timestamp etc of when the list of orders arrived in our system.

To illustrate:

```
id | date                     | XML 
1    2012-10-20 06:51:13.683   <customer name="Bill"><order oId="1">...</order><order oId="2>...</customer>
2    2012-10-20 07:30:32.833   <customer name="Ben"><order oId="23">...</order></customer>
```

I want to select all the orders out, but I also want each order to be selected alongside it's id and date. Some hypothetical results:

```
 id   |  date                  |  Customer | OrderId
 1      2012-10-20 06:51:13.683    Bill       1
 1      2012-10-20 06:51:13.683    Bill       2
 2      2012-10-20 06:51:13.683    Ben        23
```

Looking around, I've found lots of answers like [Select XML nodes using TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796408/select-xml-nodes-using-tsql) but these only deal with selecting the first instance of a node. I want to select every order node along with the other table information it's associated with.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle Example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed45b/7)

I think it's more logical to do it in two applies

```
select
    tt.id,
    tt.date,
    cust.col.value('@name', 'nvarchar(128)') as Customer,
    ord.col.value('@oId', 'int') as OrderId
from tt as tt
    outer apply tt.[xml].nodes('/customer') as cust(col)
    outer apply cust.col.nodes('order') as ord(col)
```

but you can also do it in one apply

[**SQL Fiddle Example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed45b/13)

```
select
    tt.id,
    tt.date,
    ord.col.value('../@name', 'nvarchar(128)') as Customer,
    ord.col.value('@oId', 'int') as OrderId
from tt as tt
    outer apply tt.[xml].nodes('/customer/order') as ord(col)
```

Comment: Wouldn't two apply statements be less efficient than one?

Comment: I've tested all three queries, they works almost identical, the one with ../ in it works a little longer than two others. I've tried it with different number of order inside the xml. Actually, in your answer you also have two queries to xml - one with apply and one where you get a customer name

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to update the names for your columns, but this is the approach I used:

```
SELECT xmlviewId, myDate
   , myXml.value('(customer[1]/@name)', 'varchar(10)') AS CustomerName
   , orders.value('@oId', 'VARCHAR(10)') AS OrderId
   , orders.value('../@name', 'VARCHAR(10)') AS AlternateWayToGEtCustomerName
FROM xmlView
CROSS APPLY myXml.nodes('//order') AS c(orders);
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57a2b/18/0) Example

Here's a good example for xquery [**value**](http://www.jasonstrate.com/2010/11/xquery-for-the-non-expert-value/)

I added a second way to obtain the customerName, depending on your preference.

Comment: I think it would be more logical to get customers first and then get relevant orders from that customer, see my answer

Comment: @RomanPekar I couldn't remember if the `../` syntax worked for XML data like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://janosch.woschitz.org/parse-xml-in-t-sql-via-xquery/) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@` to specify an attribute, so your query would be something like this:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT, [Date] DATETIME, [XML] XML);
INSERT @T VALUES 
    (1, '20121020 06:51:13.683', '<customer name="Bill"><order oId="1"></order><order oId="2"></order></customer>'),
    (2, '20121020 07:30:32.833', '<customer name="Ben"><order oId="23"></order></customer>');

SELECT  ID,
        [Date],
        [Customer] = [XML].value('(customer/@name)[1]', 'nvarchar(200)'),
        [OrderID] = t.Orders.value('(@oId)[1]', 'int')
FROM    @T
        CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('/customer/order') t (Orders)
```